# How to iterate over exploded (array) queryparam in Mockoon response?

Tags: mocking, handlebars.js, mockoon

### **TL;DR** How can I work with an array returned by a handlebar helper in a subexpression?

I am using mockoon (https://mockoon.com/) to mock my APIs for development purposes. Mockoon utilizes handlebars templating (https://handlebarsjs.com/).

I have one endpoint which takes an array via queryParameter with `explode=true` (https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/). Meaning, it is specified like:

```
http://my-api/endpoint?arrayParam=first&arrayParam=second&arrayParam=third
```

In my mockoon response I access the parameter value using the `queryParam` helper (https://mockoon.com/docs/latest/templating/mockoon-request-helpers/#queryparam).

For example:

```
{
  {{#each (queryParam 'arrayParam')}}  
    "{{this}}": ""{{#unless @last}},{{/unless}}  
  {{/each}}
}
```

With the goal being to end up with:

```
{
    "first": "",
    "second": "",
    "third": ""
}
```

However this generates the following:

```
{
    "[&quot;first&quot;,&quot;second&quot;,&quot;third&quot;]": ""
}
```

so it seems that the helper is returning a stringified (and escaped) array, and my question is how I can work with this?

Comment: Would you be able to share the value of `queryParam 'arrayParam'` by adding `{{log (queryParam 'arrayParam')}}` and posting the result here?

Comment: Thanks for engaging @76484 ... this ended up being more straightforward than I realized. I have followed up with an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, after a lot of digging this ended up being straight forward. It seems that `queryParamRaw` (https://mockoon.com/docs/latest/templating/mockoon-request-helpers/#queryparamraw) is for this exact purpose. So the following accomplished what I wanted:

```
{
  {{#each (queryParamRaw 'arrayParam')}}  
    "{{this}}": ""{{#unless @last}},{{/unless}}  
  {{/each}}
}
```

**N.B.** The one gotcha I ran into with this though, is if you end up in a scenario where there is only one `arrayParam` specified, then `queryParamRaw` will return `singleValue` as compared to `[singleValue]` and that single string ends up getting treated as an array of characters which causes issues... to make things more testable/mockable I am actually going back and using `explode=false` with `form` style params (`arrayParam=first,second,third`).